# My elements flow out from the screen and they are not aligned vertically

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

Elements in this layout flow out from the screen. I would like to set size of them to 90% of screen.I am XML beginner.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="1.0">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:text="@string/login_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need to put elements inside of linear layout to column.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make them to occupy 90% of the screen you need to put `weightSum` to 10 and the `layout-weight` of each element to 2.25 in order to have the 10% of your screen free.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/first"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:text="@string/login_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use attributes like "layout_centerVertical" and "layout_below" with LinearLayout. They are used with RelativeLayout.
You can achieve your layout using this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:text="Username"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:inputType="text" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.25"
        android:text="@string/login_button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fill_parent is deprecated. I suggest you to use match_parent instead if what you want is that the list width and height covers the whole screen.
Second, you are missing some tags in the LinearLayout.
In order to make the List width to cover 90% of the screen, you could do it by code in the Activity, but I suggest you to use padding and margins to leave a little bit of room on the edges, it's way easier.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Login"
            android:inputType="text" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Login" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Doing this you are telling to `LinearLayout` to distribute the elements inside with the same space not at 90% horizontally in a column. If you want to do that, you have to set the `orientation` to vertical and set some paddingRight to `LinearLayout`.

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/login_layout" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:gravity="right" 
  android:weightSum="1.0"
  android:paddingRight="20dp">
  <TextView android:id="@+id/username" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:text="Username" 
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" 
  />
  <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/login" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"  
    android:inputType="text" 
  /> 
  <EditText 
    android:id="@+id/password" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/first" 
    android:inputType="textPassword" 
  />
  <Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/password"  
    android:text="@string/login_button" 
  />
</LinearLayout>
```